# My Face class does not seem to be immutable even though I already declared it as final, how do I correct it?

Tags: java, immutability, transpose

I am trying to make my Face class immutable such that my Face object will not change once it has been initialized. This is what I have so far:

```
public class Face{
  protected final int[][] grid;
  protected Face half;

  public Face(int[][] grid){
    this.grid = grid;
  }


  public Face rotateRight(){
    int rows = 3;
    int cols = 3;
    int[][] transposedArray = new int[3][3];

    for (int i = 0; i<rows; i++){
      for (int j = 0; j<cols; j++){
        transposedArray[i][j]=grid[rows-j-1][i];
      }
    }

    return new Face(transposedArray);
  }

  public Face rotateLeft(){
    int rows = 3;
    int cols = 3;
    int[][] transposedArray = new int[3][3];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
      for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
        transposedArray[2-j][i] = grid[i][j];
      }
    }
    return new Face(transposedArray);
  }

  public Face rotateHalf(){
    half = this.rotateRight();
    half = half.rotateRight();
    return half;
  }

  public int[][] getGrid(){
    return (this.grid).clone();
    }

  public String toString(){
    String str = "";
    for (int i = 0; i<3;i++){
      for (int j = 0; j<3; j++){
        str += String.format("%02d",grid[i][j]);
      }
    }
    String str1 = str.substring(0,6);
    String str2 = str.substring(6,12);
    String str3 = str.substring(12,18);
    return str1+"\n"+str2+"\n"+str3;
  }
}
```

However, when I try to run the following:

```
int[][] g = f.getGrid();
g[1][1] = 9;
```

I expect f to remain as

```
010203
040507
070809
```

but I end up getting

```
010203
040906
070809
```

instead. Is my Face object not made immutable even though I have already declared the class as final?

Comment: `final` makes the variable, in this case, a reference, immutable. you can't change the reference but you can change the thing the reference refers to.

Comment: Elaborating on what pvg said: The important point about `final` is that you **musn't** change the thing the reference points to, not that you can't, or your object isn't immutable anymore.  `final` doesn't prevent that, so therefore you must make a copy yourself of the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a defensive copy of the input `grid` in the constructor.

Also, the fields should be `private` as well, and the class should be `final` too, although I suspect those last two points are not the cause of your problem.

Not tested:

```
  public Face(int[][] grid){
    int temp[][] = new int[ grid.length ][];
    for( int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++ ) 
      temp[i] = Arrays.copyOf( grid[i], grid[i].length );
    this.grid = temp;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could be that your constructor doesn't clone the incoming array. So maybe the code that creates the Face class instance later manipulates the array it passed to the new Face object!

Unfortunately, there is no way to create truly immutable arrays in the Java. Declaring an array as final only prevents you from changing the array as a whole, it is still possible to change individual rows, columns, slots in that array.

If you want immutable collections, you need to turn actual Collection classes and then use the methods within the Collections class to create unmodifiable views over them.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful when using `clone`.

On arrays, it does a shallow copy. The following snippet explains it better:

```
int[] c0 = new int[]{1, 2, 3};
int[] c1 = new int[]{4, 5, 6};
int[] c2 = new int[]{7, 8, 9};
int[][] grid = new int[][]{c0, c1, c2};
int[][] cloned = grid.clone();

assert cloned[0] == c0;
assert cloned[1] == c1;
assert cloned[2] == c2;
```