# Java stop variable from getting updated of a class

Tags: java, class, oop

I am facing a problem as my class variable gets automatically updated with the latest value. But I want separate value for each of the object.

```
public class B {

    public String state; 

    public B(){    
        this.state = "new";
    }

    public void firstMethod(){

        this.state = "first";          

    }

    public void secondMethod(){        

        this.state = "second";
    }

}


public abstract class C {

    public B b;    

    public C(B service){       
        this.b = service;
    }

    public abstract void execute();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
            B b = new B();
        C c = new C(b) {
            @Override
            public void execute() {               
                b.firstMethod();

            }
        };  

        C c1 = new C(b) {
            @Override
            public void execute() {               
                b.secondMethod();

            }
        }; 

    c.execute();
    c1.execute();
    System.out.println(c.b.state);

    System.out.println(c1.b.state);
}
```

I am getting c and c1 both state equal to "second". I know if I create two separate B object i.e. b1 and b2 and pass those in c and c1 while initializing then it would give me different result as I am expecting. But is there any way to get c.state as "first" and c1.state as "second" with passing the same object to both c and c1?

Comment: But probably it's a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55175471/my-face-class-does-not-seem-to-be-immutable-even-though-i-already-declared-it-as/55175486#55175486

Comment: where are you calling `execute()` on your objects?

Comment: Think what you are asking: *"I have 3 people. I give person C the home address of person B, and I give person C1 the home address of person B. I then tell person C to go to the home address they have and paint the person living there red. I then tell person C1 to go to the home address they have and paint the person living there blue. After that I check what color person B is, and they are always painted blue. Can I somehow make that person B is both a red painted person and a blue painted person?"* No, no you cannot.

Comment: I agree. Suppose, I need to inject C and C1 to an array list. Then, is there any way to see the difference between the associated state of C and C1? May be adding some properties in any one of the class or variables that will allow me to store the associated state value with C and C1?

Answer (score 0):

Your `c` and `c1` share the exact same `B` object, namely `b`.

Since the `state` we are discussing belongs to `b`, there is only one of them - called `b.state`.

If you want `state` to be different, you cannot use the same `B` object with both `C` objects.

This likely boils down to a misunderstanding of the reference semantics of assignment and parameter passing.  Neither assignment nor parameter-passing makes a copy of an object.

> But is there any way to get c.state as "first" and c1.state as
>   "second" with passing the same object to both c and c1?

This could not possibly work.  Suppose a single `B` object could somehow have any number of values of `state`.  Whenever you wrote `b.state`, how would the system know which one you meant?

Well, that's not entirely true as I wrote it.  If the constructor of `C` only used its `B` object to make an entirely new copy, such that it kept the copy rather than the original, then you'd achieve the effect; there would be three `B` objects in the world, the original, the copy made by `c`, and the copy made by `c1`.  But that has no advantage here over just passing in separate `B` instances to begin with.

Comment: Yes I got your point. Actually I was thinking whether it will be a good idea to create a  new object or there is another way of dealing this situation. So I think I need to create two separte b object when create c and c1.

Comment: "separate B" seems the simple approach, unless this is just an illustration of some actual situation that would make it more complicated.

Comment: Actually in my context, I am highly restricted to create a separate B. Can you tell me if there is another class A. And B extends A. in that case, how would I tackle this problem with copy constrcutor or may adopt any other approach?

Answer (score 0):

You used the same instance of B class into your 2 objects, so your state variable will always get updated by the last called method, you need to use another instance of B to have two separated **state** property.